# JQuery mouseenter div to pause animation resume duration restarts when mouseleave

Tags: jquery

I whant to have an animation pause when certain div has mouseenter and resume when mouseleave.
The problem is that when the animation resumes it restarts the duration and it becomes pregressively slower.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.timer').animate({ 'width': 940 }, { queue: false, duration: 5000, easing: 'linear' });

    $('.slider_app').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.timer').stop();          
    });

    $('.slider_app').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.timer').animate({ 'width': 940 }, { queue: false, duration: 5000, easing: 'linear'});
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you want to use something like this: http://tobia.github.com/Pause/ -- jQuery can't do it natively that I know of.  That plugin's pretty small/simple

Comment: Take a look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j4SNS/)

Comment: My problem is that I can't restart the duration from where it stops.
I tried to save the duration in a variable or set a timer but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Roy Finley Why don't you post that as an answer? It seems to wrok exactly as the OP has described.